# how to exclude or setnull on some parameter if edittext is empty

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, callable-statement

I have a stored procedure with alot of parameters for filtering 
i have 2 edittext Cardnumber and Carcode and both of thoose have to be filled before i can get any results

so my question is how do i get the result if one of them is empty or if they both are empty

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) {
                        z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                    } else {
                        doerTicket = setingPreferences.getString("doerTicket", "");
                        CallableStatement cs = null;
                        String query = "exec [file].[usp_getParts] \n@p_ItemNumber = ?,\n@p_DoerTicket = ?,\n@p_CarItemNumber = ?;
                        cs = con.prepareCall(query);
                        cs.setString(1, Cardnumber);//edittext(@p_ItemNumber)
                        cs.setString(2, doerTicket);
                        cs.setString(3, Carcode);//edittext(@p_CarItemNumber)
                        ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
                        while (rs.next()) {

                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    z = "Exceptions";
                }
                return z;

            }
        }
```

the parameter i currently use in the sp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [file].[usp_getParts]
    , @p_ItemNumber VARCHAR ( 3000 ) = NULL
    , @p_CarItemNumber NVARCHAR ( 20 ) = NULL
    , @p_DoerTicket VARCHAR ( 200 ) = NULL
```

with itemnumber
[image: with itemnumber]
with carcode
[image: with carcode]

or i can also get the result by using

```
EXEC    @return_value = [file].[usp_getParts]
        @p_CarItemNumber  = NULL,
        @p_ItemNumber = N'*****',
        @p_DoerTicket = N'0x01000000f475bad9ea7d1f1d6b142a1b8cc95ce74b3f387cb1388a80097f35a8c1e9131ffa7f4b833553bede4a3abec49254373d06fb3294c60c6d24',
        @p_SearchSessionID = @p_SearchSessionID OUTPUT,
        @p_TotalRows = @p_TotalRows OUTPUT
```

Comment: Somehow your question is confusing: you write that both fields have to filled, but you ask how you get the result if one or both are empty!?

Comment: Just a clarification: are you looking for a way to avoid setting statement parameters if any `params` is null?

Comment: yes thats because i need to have them both filled before i can get the result 
from it

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi yes so it doesn't fill the param if my edittext is empty

Comment: i postet 2 pictures that might get a better view of what i am trying to do

Comment: Having said that I don't know your datasource language, does it have a wildcard value for "any"?

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi the SP accepts * wildcard if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove any parameter from a statement; I suggest you to use a wildcard for setting statement parameters which are not passed to the function:

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
String query = "exec [file].[usp_getParts] \n@p_ItemNumber = ?,\n@p_DoerTicket = ?,\n@p_CarItemNumber = ?";
cs = con.prepareCall(query);
cs.setString(1, Cardnumber != null ? Cardnumber : "*");//edittext(@p_ItemNumber)
cs.setString(2, doerTicket != null ? doerTicket : "*");
cs.setString(3, Carcode != null ? Carcode : "*");//edittext(@p_CarItemNumber)
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

This way you can have a single query to extract data with any filter combination.

If you don't want to contact the datasource if some filter is not passed, you could simply check them before preparing the statement and return an error string (or maybe better throw an application exception).

Comment: i still doens't gets any results as it seems like Carcode do not support is only wildcards and so do some of the other parameters 
so are there some how i can use  @p_CarItemNumber  = NULL instead as that works for all the parameters

Comment: sorry I do not understand your comment

Comment: i am not sure how else to explain this as i tryed to explain my carcode do not support wildcard so that one do not work and instead it should use @p_CarItemNumber = NULL like i explained in my question with both code and pictures

Comment: Have you tried to set a null `Carcode` as third parameter? Isn't it working? I also foud that `CallableStatement` support a [setNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setNull(java.lang.String,%20int)) method: may it helps you?

Comment: `cs.setString(4, Cardnumber != null ? Cardnumber : null);//edittext(@p_CarItemNumber)` does not work and setnull only supports datatypes such as integer varchar NULL so i cannot use Cardnumber there